# An exception occurred during the Install phase.System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service already exists

Tags: .net, web-services

This error i am getting when i am installing the webservice which i have been given..

since i have no idea about webservice ,i am finding it difficult where to locate the name.

i have some vb file and resx file.

where can i locate the name of service any guess. The service name  given in error msg , is not present anywhere

Answer (score 0):

That error sounds more like your program is trying to install a Windows Service vs. a Web Service.  Try going to the services explorer and seeing if any of the listed services have a name like the one you are developing

- Control Panel
- Administrative Tools
- Services

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't building the solution...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @DarinKolev, you may notice that he IS the OP.